# Caption for multiple series in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a code to generate multiple charts for a single series.

code :

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [[6, 540], [7, 540], [7, 1620], [8, 1620]]
    },{
        data: [[6, 340], [7, 340], [7, 620], [8, 620]]
    }]
});
```

i need to provide different caption for the series'.. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a `name` to your definition of series ... as shown in the [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Series 1',
        data: [[6, 540], [7, 540], [7, 1620], [8, 1620]]
    },{
        name: 'Series 2',
        data: [[6, 340], [7, 340], [7, 620], [8, 620]]
    }]
});
```

Comment: The above code works very fine for column charts..take a look at this snippet, i need to add a caption for each and every chart.the chart type is pie. http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/x9Tfp/

Comment: After playing around with the jsfiddle for awhile I only came up with: `labels:{ items:[{ html:'Product name', style:{ left: '240px',
 top: '30px', color: 'black' } } ] },`

Comment: Hi, 
   I tried making use of this approach before, but the caption serves its purpose, for the whole chart and not for every pie. I need to display it for every chart. very much thankful for your response.